# tidy eval vs base or get() vs sym() vs as.symbol()

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

I have been trying to understand tidy eval or how to use variables within tidyverse for a while, but I never seem to fully grasp it.

For example, I am trying to use ggplot with variable mappings. This would the base R version:

```
library(ggplot2)
var1 = "wt"
var2 = "mpg"
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = get(var1), y = get(var2))) + geom_point()
```

However, based on all the documentation and discussion I have seen, the "proper" quasiquotation way would be:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = !!sym(var1), y = !!sym(var2))) + geom_point()
```

Maybe that is more comparable to:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = !!as.symbol(var1), y = !!as.symbol(var2))) + geom_point()
```

The `get()` method is shorter and more readable to me. Why is it shunned by the tidyverse community?

Comment: fwiw, the "old" sanctioned way of using ggplot with aesthetic mappings stored in characters was to use `aes_string()` not `get()`.

Comment: One difference is that your x and y axis labels are `get(var1)` and `get(var2)`.  I suspect https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#quosures is related.

Comment: @joran I did not mention the `aes_` functions since they are now soft-deprecated, so at least there is some reason not to use them.

Comment: I think perhaps part of what's going on here is that ggplot itself was rewritten to use quosures; I feel like when I first learned ggplot using `get` in this fashion would break in unanticipated ways bc the evaluation scheme was more fragile.

Answer (score 4):

If the data frame contains a `var1` or `var2` column, those will be picked up by `get()` instead of the objects in your environment.

Also you'll get better auto-labelling of the expression with quasiquotation, as you're modifying the captured expression directly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super familiar with tidyeval and I could be wrong about this. My understanding is that tidy evaluation is more useful for slightly more complicated exercises such as combining `dplyr` or `tidyr` with `ggplot2`, or handling multiple arguments ([dot-dot-dot](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/multiple.html#the-...-argument)). Here’s a function which takes grouped variables passed by `...`, calculates the mean for `.summary_var` then plot the results:

```
library(tidyverse)
gg_dummy_func <- function(.data, .summary_var, ...) {

  summary_var <- enquo(.summary_var)
  group_vars <- enquos(...)

  sum_data <- .data %>%
    group_by(!!!group_vars) %>%
    summarise(mean=mean(!!summary_var))

  gg <- ggplot(sum_data, aes(x=!!sym(names(sum_data)[1]), 
                             y=!!sym(names(sum_data)[2]),
                             color=mean)) +
    geom_point()
  print(gg)
}


gg_dummy_func(mtcars, mpg, wt, cyl)
```

[image]